# ¿Por que Me sale este Error?

Tags: c#, sql-server

les pongo en contexto, tengo esta parte del código, inserto un registro a una tabla pero por alguna razón, en mi computadora y en una pc de escritorio si ingresa los datos a la Tabla CANCELACIONES pero en otras 2 computadoras diferentes me genera un error...

```
String InsertarRenovacion = "INSERT INTO CANCELACIONES";
                    InsertarRenovacion += "VALUES('" + numeritocliente.Text + "'," + numeritodepoliza.Text + ",'" + datetime2.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "','" + razon.Text + "', '" + datetime1.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "', '" + Observaciones.Text + "','"+clave+"',"+CanprimaNeta.Text+","+Canprimatotal.Text+",'"+Estado.Text+"')";
                    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
                    comando.Connection = MenuInicio.conexion;
                    comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    comando.CommandText = InsertarRenovacion;
                    try
                    {
                        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        comando.Dispose();
                        comando = null;
                    }
```

[image: Este error me genera en 2 pc de escritorio, sin embargo en mi laptop y en la PC de un compañero no genera ningún error.]

Aqui es donde cree mi tabla, primero tenia primary key de tipo Int Identity(1,1), se lo quite por que no necesito primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE CANCELACIONES(Poliza Varchar(9), NumPoliza INT NOT NULL,
FechaCancelacion DATE NOT NULL, Razon VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, FechadeIngreso date null, Observaciones Varchar(250) null, Listo VARCHAR(5) null,
CanNeta Numeric(10,2) not null, CanTotal Numeric(10,2),EstAnt Varchar(20),
CONSTRAINT FK_CANCELACIONES_NumPoliza FOREIGN KEY (NumPoliza) REFERENCES DATOSSEGURO(NumPoliza))
GO
```

Comment: Este valor **numeritocliente.Text**, en que campo de la tabla debe ir? Creo que te falta el cliente en la tabla

Comment: numeritocliente.text va en Poliza, ingreso 10 valores y la tabla es de 10 valores, en 2 computadoras si funciona y en otras 2 marca el error que aparece en la captura de pantalla bro... mi duda es por que yo si puedo agregar y la otra pc igual puede agregar y no manda ese error.

Comment: Falta un espacio entre *Cancelaciones* y *Values*; no sé si será eso pero no se pierde nada probando :( . También podrías probar a convertir los números con parse

Comment: es por que habia probado hacerlo asi:
 String InsertarRenovacion = "INSERT INTO CANCELACIONES (Poliza,NumPoliza,FechaCancelacion,Razon,FechadeIngreso,Observaciones,Listo,CanNeta,CanTotal,EstAnt)";

pero tampoco

Comment: Debes usar agregando en la sentencia del insert el nombre de las columnas. Con esa modificación tienes el mismo error?

Comment: Si, acabo de leer que podría ser por que hice una modificación en mi tabla, permitanme generar ideas para la solucion de mi problema... a mi tabla cancelaciones le agregue 3 columnas... le elimine la llave primaria y agregue todos los datos que tenia desde el sql server... en mi computadora agarra por que tengo sql server... y en la pc también tiene sql server... Podria ser que no se haya actualziado la tabla para el Cliente y solo se actualizo para el propio servidor?

Comment: naa, lo que dije no tiene lógica alguna... no podría ser... es como si en las otras 2 pc se agregaran a una tabla diferente que tiene mas columnas que las que ingreso...

Comment: @JesusDanielVazquezLorenzo replique tu codigo y me lanzó error como a ti. La solución fue lo que te comenté; falta el espacio entre cancelaciones y values

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, mañana te comento si solucione el problema (Ya que el servidor es una LAN). de igual manera gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: Sigo con mi problema, aunque creo que no es problema de código si no de la base de datos... ya que en 3 computadoras puedo agregar registros y en 2 no...

Answer (score 0):

El error es muy claro, las tablas que tienes no coinciden en el orden en que estas realizando el insert, te recomiendo que restructures el query del insert y puedas ver que campo te este faltando.

```
String InsertarRenovacion = "INSERT INTO CANCELACIONES(poliza,numpoliza,fechacancelacion,razon,fechadeingreso,observaciones,listo,canneta,cantotal,estant) ";
                    InsertarRenovacion += "VALUES('" + numeritocliente.Text + "'," + numeritodepoliza.Text + ",'" + datetime2.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "','" + razon.Text + "', '" + datetime1.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "', '" + Observaciones.Text + "','"+clave+"',"+CanprimaNeta.Text+","+Canprimatotal.Text+",'"+Estado.Text+"')";
                    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
                    comando.Connection = MenuInicio.conexion;
                    comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    comando.CommandText = InsertarRenovacion;
                    try
                    {
                        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        comando.Dispose();
                        comando = null;
                    }
```

Comment: como comentaba anterior mente y en la publicación, desde que lo probé en mi pc funcionaba y si fuera ese error no hubiese funcionado, después de esas pruebas y errores lo pase a las 4 primeras pc... y funcionaba, después de eso pase la App en otras dos y allí no funcionaban ya.